# .htacess - Remove .html from the homepage but not from folders within within that website

Tags: htaccess, redirects, html, apache

I'm trying to remove the `.html` from my landing page, an example would be instead of `domain.com/contact.html` it would be `domain.com/contact` while at the same time keeping the `.html` for all the folders within the website, so `domain.com/components/file.html` would stay as a `.html`..

So in other words redirect for the landing page, but not for all the other files on my server..

This is the code I'm currently using to remove the `.html` but it also removes it for all the other directories as well.

```
#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Would anyone have any advice on this matter?

Comment: It's really best if you use the same account to answer with that you asked the question with, or merge them. See this:  [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Remarkably similar (but different) question posted on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457398/redirect-http-to-https-and-remove-html-from-pages

Comment: Cross-site post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458281/remove-html-from-the-homepage-but-not-from-folders-within-within-that-website

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, I found the solution:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.[^\/]*)$ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /$1.html [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> #301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
> RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Let's focus on this one, as the one you want to change. Firstly I would say the THE_REQUEST is just adding complication. I guess its purpose is to 'stop' the rule adding the html back, removed during the first 'internal' redirect.

... I would suggest that it's much better just to 'fix' that by putting the URL first. ie. have the 301 removing the extension FIRST. (It has `L` in it anyway.)  Then have the internal redirect.

Then it seems you just need

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

`[^/]` means match anything except a slash. So then paths with a slash in them (eg folders!) won't match.

You may also want to consider adding:

```
RewriteBase /
```

to the beginning of the file to make sure that relative paths work. ie that the rewrite rule isn't matching a path that already has slashes at start.

Alternatively use:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The check against `THE_REQUEST` is still required in a per-directory (`.htaccess`) context in order to prevent a redirect loop (as you suggest).  Simply changing the order of these directives is not sufficient. The `L` flag simply stops the _current_ round of processing, the rewriting process then effectively starts over. (This is in `.htaccess`, as opposed to the server config.) Also, the `RewriteBase` directive does not affect what is _matched_, as you seem to imply. `RewriteBase` only overrides the directory-prefix that is added back on relative path _substitutions_.